# If $f(x)=p \sin x + q x \cos x + x^2$ and $f(2)=3$, find $f(-2)$

Tags: trigonometry, solution-verification, gre-exam

A GRE subject trig question:

> Let $p,q$ be constants and let $$f(x)=p \sin x + q x \cos x + x^2$$ for all real numbers $x$. If $f(2)=3$, find $f(-2)$.

So I plug in and obtain

$$3=\phantom{-}p \sin 2 +2q \cos 2 + 4$$
$$y=-p\sin 2 -2q \cos 2 + 4$$

Adding them, I obtain

$$3+y= 8$$

Where $y$ is *what*; that is, is the answer $5$?

Comment: Should be $y = - p\sin 2 - 2q \cos 2 + 4$

Comment: but I thought cosine is an even function so plugging in negative doesn't come out?

Comment: @Gregory but I thought for cos, $\cos(-x)=\cos(x)$?

Comment: oh my gosh, the $x$ in the way..

Comment: Yes, your revised answer is correct.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig thanks!! Cant believe I made such a silly error.

Comment: @MyMathYourMath I think this is a good problem. Can I get the source of this problem, please?